# Class template and type

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T>class node{};
```

Now, if I were to use  the following template definition in my `.hpp` file

```
template<typename node<T>> class list{};
```

the code doesn't compile:

[Compiler Log](https://pastebin.com/9BQ3N02u)

But if I were to change the definition to

```
template<typename X> class list{};
```

And use `node<string>` to substitute for `X` during instantiation, everything works fine.

I would like to understand why the code doesn't compile in the first case? AFAIK, `node<T>` is a distinct type by itself just like `X`.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: `template<typename node<T>> class list{};` is not valid C++. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. You might be looking for `template<typename T> class list{...};` and then using `node<T>` within the definition of `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, this does not work:

```
template<typename node<T>>
```

That's because the token after `typename` is supposed to be the name given to a template argument, not the combination of a name (T) and an existing type.

If you want to constrain your template class to make sure the thing it uses is a node, you can either do this:

```
template<typename T>
class list{ /* use node<T> here */ };
```

Or this, if you merely want to make it a suggestion and not a hard requirement:

```
template<typename T, typename N = node<T>>
class list{ /* use N here */ };
```

In either of these cases, `list<int>` will use `node<int>` internally.